# preg_match any number followed by cm (centimeters)

Tags: php, regex, csv

So, I have some csv files with products (id, description, price etc) and I need to find a regular expression that will consistently match any number followed by cm (centimeters), which should be the product's height.

The height could be, for example, 35 cm. , 35cm , 35 cm 
or in Greek 35 εκ. , 35εκ , 35 εκ

However, I need the preg_match to return only the number, not the cm/εκ part

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
/\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?(?=\s*(?:cm|εκ))/gi
```

View https://regex101.com/r/3hOu77/4 for examples

Comment: wow!!! what an amazing tool. I will at last learn regex. By the way your expression works for cm , but I need it to work for it's Greek equivalent as well

Comment: Does it not work for the greek equivalent? Is the sign εκ ? If so, it should work (see the website, there is a number with it)

Comment: nice, you added the εκ part in the regex. Now it works for both cm and εκ. But how to make it case insensitive?

Comment: I updated the regex to include the g flag (which finds more than one) and the i flag (which makes it case insensitive)

Comment: hmmm, after some testing, if a number has decimals, it returns only the decimals. So if there's a 35,5 cm it returns 5 instead of 35,5  . And the decimal point could also be a dot instead of a comma

Comment: Updated the answer to accomodate for decimals